# Increase parskip in tcblisting output

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting

How to increase the `\parskip` in the output of a `tcblisting`, i.e. the vertical space between the black squares in the following example?

Neither the `\parskip` of the surrounding text nor the spacing of the displayed code should be affected and no additional code should be shown.

*(alternatively: changing the `linespread` or anything else to increase the vertical distance is also fine)*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{%
    sidebyside,
    listing options={language={[latex]TeX}},
    center lower,
    righthand width=3cm
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tcblisting}{title={test}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `before lower={\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}}` here since the output of the displayed code is displayed in the lower box, which is here `sidebyside`, replace the value of `10pt` at will.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{%
    sidebyside,
    listing options={language={[latex]TeX}},
    center lower,
    righthand width=3cm,
    before lower={\setlength{\parskip}{50pt}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tcblisting}{title={test}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great - just have to wait 7 min until I am allowed to accept your answer.

Comment: @samcarter: 7mins can be a long time. That's almost the time the light needs for traveling from the Sun to the Earth ;-)

Comment: And it is longer then it took you to answer the question :) This means you have to be somewhere within 0.5 AU from Earth - now that your location is known so precisely you should probably expect tcolorbox noobs like me waiting on your doorstep to ask questions...

Comment: @samcarter: I am a space - like vector ... translight speed is possible for me ;-)

Comment: @samcarter: By the way: Can't you use a StarGate like the 'other' Sam(antha) Carter? ;-)

Comment: Psst - that's secret! Cannot talk on the internet about that :)